# mysql phrase search

Tags: php, mysql

I have the above sql code and when i will run it return error, can you help me how to resolve it?

$keyword= variable in php
the sql table is data(id,source,title,description,h1)
                    $sql = "SELECT * ,
                      MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$keyword') AS rel1,
                      MATCH (source) AGAINST ('$keyword') AS rel2,
                     FROM data
                      WHERE MATCH (title,source) AGAINST ('$keyword')
                       ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2)
                       LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit ";

error
sql You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM data WHERE MATCH (title,source) AGAINST ('') ' at line 4

my webserver have
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.1.51 mysql
php server
ngix server

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra comma. Try this:

```
SELECT * , MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$keyword') AS rel1, MATCH (source) AGAINST ('$keyword') AS rel2 FROM data WHERE MATCH (title,source) AGAINST ('$keyword') ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2) LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit
```

Also you might need to replace ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2) with matches, not sure aliases work here as well.